# Unable to train LUIS model in rasa-nlu

Tags: rasa-nlu

I have installed Python 3.6.8 and installed rasa on windows 10 1809 build using below instructions

```
pip install rasa pip install rasa[spacy] python -m spacy download en_core_web_md python -m spacy link en_core_web_md en
```

created a folder `c:\chatbot` and ran below command `cd c:\chatbot rasa init`, which created data, models and other folders/files in chatbot folder.

I deleted files under data folder as documented in Rasa as open source alternative to Microsoft LUIS - Migration Guide and copied luis model(as json file) into data folder.

After copying ran below command, which gave below error.

```
c:\chatbot>rasa train nlu -vv 
2019-06-23 15:17:11 DEBUG rasa.skill - Selected skills: No NLU data given.
Please provide NLU data in order to train a Rasa NLU model using the ‘–nlu’ argument.
```

unable to import LUIS model and train it. Appreciate help in getting over this issue.

Thanks, Prasad

Answer (score 2):

I think you actually found a bug in `rasa`. I created this issue for it: https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/issues/3853

As a workaround, please try to convert your data first:

```
rasa data convert nlu --data <path to your json file> -f md --out converted-rasa-file.md
mv <path to your json file> <somewhere-out-of-the-data-directory
```

Update: The issue was fixed in `rasa` `1.1.5`

Then you should be able to train with `rasa train`.

Comment: Rasa community has confirmed the same. below link has additional details
https://forum.rasa.com/t/unable-to-train-luis-model/11936

Comment: Hi Tobias, 
Can you please confirm if the issue is fixed? I tried today morning(IST) and issue is still present.

Comment: it's fixed in rasa `1.1.5`